# Why isn't this for-loop ever executing?

Tags: c, networking, for-loop

Right now, I'm trying to write a simple TCP client/server program that measures, among other things, the RTT over an ethernet LAN. However, I'm having some trouble with the following function:

```
void iteratedSend(int iterations, int msgSize, bool useRTT){
    printf("started iteratedSend for size %d\n",msgSize);//DEBUG STATEMENT 1
    int i;
    double elapsedTime = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < iterations; i++){
        printf("iteration %d", i);//DEBUG STATEMENT 2
        elapsedTime += timeMessage(msgSize, true);
    }
    if(!useRTT)
        elapsedTime = elapsedTime / 2.0;

    double throughput = (msgSize * iterations) / elapsedTime;
    printf("Message Size: %d bytes  Elapsed Time: %f ms  Throughput: %f Bps\n" ,
        msgSize, elapsedTime, throughput);

    fprintf(outputFile, "Message Size: %d bytes  Elapsed Time: %f ms  Throughput: %f
        Bps\n" ,  msgSize, elapsedTime, throughput); 
    fprintf(dataFile, "%.3d , %.3f\n" ,  msgSize, throughput);
```

}

Oddly enough, the line of code marked "DEBUG STATEMENT 1" is printed, so the function is successfully starting, but the statement "DEBUG STATEMENT 2" is never printed, and the loop never executed. When this happens, my client and server hang indefinitely.

The place where this hanging takes place is in main, when the following line of code is executed:

```
iteratedSend(1, 1024000,false);
```

Any ideas on what exactly is going on here? Apologies in advance for any violations of convention in my C-code; C is still very much a new language for me.

Thanks!

Comment: After your debug statements, add `fflush(stdout);` as you are using by default buffered I/O and the message may be output to stdout but not show up for this reason.... which would mean you are in `timeMessage()` when you hang potentially.

Comment: Alternatively, add `\n` to the format sstring your second `printf()` call.

Comment: Are you sure that where you do the division `throughput = (msgSize * iterations) / elapsedTime;` that `elapsedTime` is not still 0?

Comment: Thanks for the reply JohnH. The line was failing to print for the exact reason you speculated: I wasn't flushing stdout. The program was indeed hanging in timeMessage.

Sorry I can't up vote your comment; being new to StackOverflow, I've got a bit farther to go before I get up vote privileges.